# How to get to desktop of any user by text file?

Tags: file, batch-file

I have ini file that I read in my program.

The ini file need to contain the desktop of any user.

How to write this?

`%user%/windows`?

Comment: I don't know your context, but having `.ini` file on the desktop will make the desktop messy. To store settings, you may put such files somewhere under `%APPDATA%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, try

```
%userprofile%\desktop
```

Comment: Wouldn't it fail in non-English versions of Windows? (I honestly don't remember how does it work, and don't have a specimen to check now).

Comment: The desktop folder can be changed by the user. This won't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get, in all cases, the actual desktop path :

```
for /f "tokens=3" %i in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop"') do @set desktop=%i
echo %desktop%
```

Actually, the desktop path can be changed. The value is stored under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Desktop`.

Do not forget to double `%` if you run this in a batch file.